# How to add video track to Scala GUI?

Tags: scala, scalafx

I'd like to display a video in GUI and I'm using ScalaFX API for my UI programming, and I happen to notice there's a class called VideoTrack in the API.  So does that class contain all the necessary function, and how should I implement that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find a couple of good examples using media components in ProScalaFX project: https://github.com/scalafx/ProScalaFX/tree/master/src/proscalafx/ch08